# How to bind a viewmodel to a bottomsheet

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-viewmodel

I am trying to figure out how to bind a viewmodel to a bottomsheet in a way that I can have the bottomsheet both expand, collapse, and hide using observable fields on the viewmodel.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use custom [`BindingAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter.html).

```
@BindingAdapter("bottomSheetBehaviorState")
public static void setState(View v, int bottomSheetBehaviorState) {
    BottomSheetBehavior<View> viewBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(v);
    viewBottomSheetBehavior.setState(bottomSheetBehaviorState);
}
```

Bind it in xml to your view:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">  
(...)
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/group_bottom_sheet"
            bottomSheetBehaviorState="@{viewModel.bottomSheetBehaviorState}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"/>


(...)
</layout>
```

And change state in ViewModel. Related code from my ViewModel:

```
public final ObservableInt bottomSheetBehaviorState = new ObservableInt(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);


@Override
public void onAction(boolean show){
    bottomSheetBehaviorState.set(show? BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED : BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try and report back / update with anything else I find. Trying to update peekheight too. What is the namespace for bottomsheetbehaviorstate?

Comment: All states are here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html#STATE_COLLAPSED

Comment: The namespace as in  app/android/ app:behavior_hideable android:id etc... The bottomSheetBehaviorState attribute defined in the nestedscrollview element does not have a namespace

Comment: You don't need namespace for this attribute.